# Syncronize /etc directory between two debian servers

Tags: debian, sync, failover

I have two identical debian servers, which I want to keep in sync in order to switch to the 2nd in case of failure of the 1st.

I'm going to sync installed debian packages, data directories, mysql (via replication), and /etc directory.

For /etc I was wondering what I cannot sync because it would create problems, and I prepared the following list of files:

- /etc/hostname
- /etc/fstab
- /etc/passwd*
- /etc/group*
- /etc/shadow*
- /etc/gshadow*
- /etc/machine-id
- /etc/mtab
- /etc/subgid*
- /etc/varnish/secret

Am I missing anything?

Are there other files which I must care?

Comment: Have you looked into tools like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), or the like?  These tools are built to do what you want to do.

Comment: In the case I use puppet or chef do I need to define the server configuration in the app? or do they read and config themselves reading the master server's configuration?